# .net core ILogger not using LogLevel values from appsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console app that uses ConfigurationBuilder for reading appsettings.json and a ServiceCollection for injecting ILogger instances. It logs fine but it is way too verbose, especially Entity Framework. My attempts to limit LogLevel in appsettings are ignored.

```cs
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
var services = new ServiceCollection();
ConfigureServices(services, config);
```

In ConfigureServices I have this:

```cs
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddConfiguration(config);
    logging.AddConsole();
});
```

The presence or absence of `logging.AddConfiguration(config)` makes no difference. The appsettings.json file includes this:

```json
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "None",
    "Microsoft": "None",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "None"
  },
  "Console": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "ReportCreation": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I can read other settings from the appsettings.json file but the logging is ignoring the LogLevel. Am I missing something? TIA!

Comment: There are appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json.If you are in develpment mode,system will use appsettings.Development.json rather than appsettings.json.

Comment: Yes I know that, the same settings are in both files.

Comment: @EricKB did you ever solve this one? I have the same problem. It appears ILogger, in my case, is not using appsettings.json or appsetting.<Environment>.json either. I am getting Info and above no matter what I change the loglevel to. I've tried Trace to expand and Error to limit- neither does anything so I must be missing something.

Comment: @CyndiBaker Nope, I've not figured this out. The logging config works correctly in a web app so I presume it is some subtle wrinkle (or a bug) when in a console app.

Comment: See answer here (it helped me): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587989/netcore2-console-app-configure-loglevel-at-appsettings

Comment: @WetMouse, that link is indeed the solution adding `logging.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));`  makes the difference